# Cannot rotate imageBitmap creates error

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, rotation

So I am attempting to rotate a picture taken with the rear facing camera and then rotating it. However when I attempt to rotate it it the app crashes.

Code I am using to rotate the picture from file

```
private Bitmap rotatePhoto(File f)
{
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(270);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmp;
}
```

logcat

```
09-21 10:24:55.112: E/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setFocusAreas(const android::CameraParameters&): no autofocus support
09-21 10:24:55.112: W/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875): Auto Focus 6
09-21 10:24:55.112: E/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875):  auto exposure value: NULL
09-21 10:24:57.174: W/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875): Auto Focus 0
09-21 10:24:57.204: E/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875):  auto exposure value: NULL
09-21 10:25:01.509: E/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setFocusAreas(const android::CameraParameters&): no autofocus support
09-21 10:25:01.509: W/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875): Auto Focus 6
09-21 10:25:01.509: E/QCameraHWI_Parm(24875):  auto exposure value: NULL
09-21 10:25:03.791: I/dalvikvm(28721):   at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.rotatePhoto(ImagePreview.java:54)
09-21 10:25:03.791: I/dalvikvm(28721):   at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.initUI(ImagePreview.java:46)
09-21 10:25:03.791: I/dalvikvm(28721):   at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.onCreate(ImagePreview.java:29)
09-21 10:25:03.801: E/AndroidRuntime(28721):    at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.rotatePhoto(ImagePreview.java:54)
09-21 10:25:03.801: E/AndroidRuntime(28721):    at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.initUI(ImagePreview.java:46)
09-21 10:25:03.801: E/AndroidRuntime(28721):    at com.example.autotakecamera.ImagePreview.onCreate(ImagePreview.java:29)
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some lines in that stack trace, such as the actual exception. Also, on what hardware are you experiencing this?

Comment: it came back to the stack trace. When I was searching the log file I missed some lines. I was getting an OOM fixed it though. Good catch on the stack trace